# How to pronounce derived scientific units

Tags: pronunciation, number

I would like to know how to pronounce a derived scientific unit.

From [SI Unit and Prefix Names in Chinese](https://www.metricmethods.com/SI_chinese.html), I have been able to surmise that A/B is pronounced A每B， such that g/m would be 克每米.

However, how is the product of units pronounced, such as A.B or g.m (gram-metres)?

And, how are ratios of products pronounced? For example， A.B / (C.D), such as kg.m / (J.s) (kilogram-metres per Joule-second in English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, what you do with the product of units is you directly link them together, so like gram meters is just 克米， kilogram meters is like 千克米 or 公斤米。

And similarly kilogram-meters per Joule Second is just 千克米每焦耳秒 the "per" is just "每".

Hope that helps